# Unable to install react native due to the following errors, any idea what might be leading for this errors?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

sachin@sachin-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ npm install -g react-native-cli
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/node_modules/semver
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
/usr/local/lib
`-- react-native-cli@2.0.1` 
-- semver@5.6.0

npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-34-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "react-native-cli"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/node_modules/semver
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/node_modules/semver'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/node_modules/semver'
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/node_modules/semver' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/sachin/npm-debug.log

Answer (score 1):

When you want to install some node package globally, you need admin permission so do it as follows:

```
$sudo npm install -g react-native-cli
```

And write your password when asking.

Comment: Hey, Thank You :)

Comment: Great! Don't forget to up vote and accept my answer as the solution :), thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have write access in `/usr/local/lib/`.

This [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/869168/node-modules-have-755-permissions-what-permissions-should-i-set-so-that-npm-don) might help.